# Remove last dynamically added row

Tags: jquery

I did some all day learning and I figured out how to add rows dynamically for my form with jquery. But now I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove that last added row.

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children('.client').attr('id', 'client' + newNum).attr('name', 'client' + newNum);
                newElem.children('.color').attr('id', 'color' + newNum).attr('name', 'color' + newNum);

                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');

            });



<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">

<select name="client" id="client" class="client">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="color" id="color" class="color"/>

    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Row" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And on jsFiddle for your viewing pleasure: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P8bTz/1/)

**Answer** *Courtesy of **Blender***

```
$('#btnRemove').on('click', function() {
    $('.clonedInput').last().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so?

```
$('#btnRemove').on('click', function() {
    $('.clonedInput').last().remove();
});
​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P8bTz/2/**

Comment: Ah yes - this is it! I will accept when timer runs up. Thanks!

Comment: @user1125062 I know its so simple! but I am just learning so the simple things take me a day to learn. But once I learn it im good! only another 1k functions to go and I'm set :) haha

Answer (score 2):

Add a button and bind this line to it:

```
$(".clonedInput").last().remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.clonedInput:last').remove();
```

Comment: this is using pseudo classes where as by default give a function last to remove the last dom from a DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try the http://jsfiddle.net/P8bTz/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/P8bTz/3/ this one should exhibit also the delete button disabling behavior you wished for

Answer (score 0):

**last** of **jquery** will do the trick as:

```
$('#your_doms_id').last().remove();
```